# Form is displaying next to H1, how do I move under?

Tags: html, css

I am coding a front-end and my form class is showing up next to h1, but I want it under. Maybe something to do with my CSS file? How do I do this? Below is the complete HTML and CSS code. Running on Python Flask. I am new to front-end design so solution + explanation would be helpful. I also added a picture of the problem. Thanks!

[image: Here is the front-end]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
        <title>Cryptocurrency Price Forecast</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg">
            <ul class="glass">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1 style="color:white;" class="header">Cryptocurrency Price Forecast</h1>
        <form action="/forecast/" method="post">
            <br>
            <div class="txtani">
                <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="text" name="text" required/>
                <label for="text">Enter symbol pair...</label>
                <button class="button" type="submit"><a href="/forecast/" style="color: #ffffff;"><span>Enter</span></a></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
#text {
    display: block;
    width: 475px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #021652;
    border: 2px solid #3ba9f4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    resize: none;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  }

.button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #4800ff;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}


body {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;

}



.txtani {
  position: relative;  
}

input {
  width: 250px;
  padding: .5rem .7rem;
  border: solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: .2s;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  color: #a3a3a3;
  top: 23%;
  left: 4%;
  padding: 0 .2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: .2s;
}
input:valid ~ label{
  top: -23%;
  background: #fff;
}

input:focus ~ label{
  font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: blue;
}

.glass {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.glass li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
  bottom: -150px;
}

.glass li:nth-child(1) {
  left: 35%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.glass li:nth-child(2) {
  left: 10%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.glass li:nth-child(3) {
  left: 70%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

.glass li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 18s;
}

.glass li:nth-child(5) {
  left: 65%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.glass li:nth-child(6) {
  left: 75%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.glass li:nth-child(7) {
  left: 35%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 7s;
}

.glass li:nth-child(8) {
  left: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  animation-delay: 15s;
  animation-duration: 45s;
}

.glass li:nth-child(9) {
  left: 20%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}

.glass li:nth-child(4) {
  left: 85%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-duration: 11s;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px) rotate(720deg);
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: May be the parent element is flex, please provide the whole html with style

Comment: This isn't typical HTML behavior, meaning the error is in your CSS. Please show us the CSS for all affected items in your code.

Comment: I just added complete HTML and CSS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it looks some style defined on `.header` make thing choas.

maybe you added a `display:inline` in `.header`

you can write down an inline style in `h1` like

```
<h1 style="color:white;display:block;" class="header">Cryptocurrency Price Forecast</h1>
```

see as if it can wrap a new line